# Combining certificate chain gives PEM_read_bio:bad end line

Tags: bash, openssl

I have a simple bash script which loads and combines some x509 certificates (client + intermediate) for me. Loading the individual certificates works, but when I try to concatenate them it errors out:

```
echo "$clientCert" | openssl x509; echo "Client cert OK"
echo "$int" | openssl x509; echo "Intermediate OK"
echo "$clientCert\n$int" | openssl x509; echo "Combined OK"
```

The first two commands work fine, the last one errors with:

```
unable to load certificate
47576:error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:747:
```

I've tried every permutation of newlines and spaces I can think of, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need echo -e to print \n see https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+-e

```
$ clientCert=clientCertVAR
$ int=intVAR
$ echo "$clientCert\n$int"
clientCertVAR\nintVAR

$ echo -e "$clientCert\n$int"
clientCertVAR
intVAR
```

Try set -x to see output of your commands or the way I did an example.

Cheers

Comment: bah, I knew it was something simple. Thanks!